# Nuxt.Js Deploy without node_modules folder on Azure

Tags: nuxt.js

I have nuxt.js APP with SSR that is being deployed on Azure. All good and it works except that the deployment process takes like 10 minutes due to the `node_modules` folder.

On the server side, there is a 'standard' node js server setup.
The artifact structure that is being deployed looks like in the screenshot.

[image]

The deployment takes about 10 minutes and that is due to the `node_modules` folder. **If I remove `node_modules` from the artifact the app stops working.**

I looked around but couldn't find any good reference, of how to deploy nuxt.js app with SSR and without the `node_modules` folder on the server.

As I understand from the link below the `.nuxt` folder should be enough on the server, but I don't know how to get it running. Maybe it has something with the server setup?

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands/#production-deployment

Any tips are welcomed.

Answer (score -1):

from your question I would assume, that you want to deploy a SSR (not static) application to azure. If this is the case, it is true that you only need the .nuxt folder.

To help you with the question of the deployment I need more information. What is your setup, how do you deploy it?
Why isn't simply transferring only the .nuxt folder working?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, your assumptions are right, I will update the question.

Comment: I've updated the question and digged more in the topic. I am not sure it's even possible to deploy SSR without node_modules. 

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-azure-portal 

The `index.js` requires those files.

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit the `nuxt.config.js` file so that the target is `server`.

Ex:

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'server',
    // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
    head: {
        title: 'Test',
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: 'dk'
        },
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
        ]
    },

...
}
```

After a build you can package the artifacts without `node_modules` and it should work. You can try to do this locally:

1. `npm i`
2. `npm run build`
3. `rm -rf node_modules`
4. `npm start`

This should be able to run with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll try this out

Comment: @klodoma Did this work out for you?

Comment: @Damitha funny, I just tried it this week again. No it didn't.